# How to adjust shower drain height after replacing shower base?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower, drain, pipe

I just pulled out my shower base to replace with a completely new base. Now I have no idea if the height of this will fit:

[image]

Few questions:

1. How do I remove or cut this top piece?

[image]

2. I assume (C) is the actual drain pipe and I need to remove (A) and (B), correct?
3. Do I lay down the new shower base first and then install (B) after that? Then finally screw in (A)?

Sorry for a newbie question.

Comment: The way I usually see it done is to have the pipe just shy of the under layment (water proofing membrane) and then a female end goes gets glued on to it with the drain assembly that adjustable in height for your final tile surface. not sure if that helps. i can say if you are unsure, you probably should have a plumber help you out with this as it is the most critical to prevent problems down the road.

Comment: There are a few different ways the connections are made to the shower pan. Some are made by setting the base over the pipe and driving a donut style gasket over the pipe, into the receiver of the base. Some the pipe has to be carefully placed where the base will be, cut at the right height and a threaded portion glued in place. Then the base is set over it and the drain screwed in

Comment: What is the "A" portion? A piece left over from the breaking out of the base around it? Or was it exposed after you lifted the base from over it? And if it is broke out from around it, what is the little piece above the main part? It appears to have threads involved near it. It may be the remainder of the second type of connection I refereed to. Do not break it off the rest of the way!!!! Use it as a way to spin the rest out. Or perhaps just cut the pipe below th floor and couple a new pipe on top. More on that later on, depending on what you find.

Comment: Might beworth while, given the base you pulled out, look at it for identifying info and lookup that manufacturers instructions for this or similar models. As @Jack noted, there will be numerous ways to still solve this problem, but reducing damage will have its rewards.